# Find the limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^{\tan x}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We suppose that $f(x) = \sin x; \ g(x) = \tan x$. Then we use this technique:
$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)^{g(x)} = e^A, \ A = \lim_{x \to a}(f(x)-1)\cdot g(x),$$
\begin{multline}
\lim_\limits{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^{\tan x} = \lim_\limits{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x - 1) \tan x= \lim_\limits{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(\sin x - 1)\sin x}{\cos x} =\\= \lim_\limits{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2 x-\sin x}{\cos x} = \lim_\limits{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\cos^2 x - \sin x}{\cos x}=\\=\lim_\limits{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x} - \cos x =\dots
\end{multline}
Further it is not very clear how to remove uncertainty (remove $\cos x$ from denumerator). Help me please.

Comment: For the last bit, where the fraction is, can you not multiply by $(1+\sin x)/(1+\sin x)$? This allows you to simplify the numerator considerably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite $\frac{1-\sin x}{\cos x}$ as $\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}$.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$(\sin x)^{\tan x}=\left[(1+(\sin x -1))^\frac1{\sin x-1}\right]^{\tan x(\sin x-1)}\to e^0=1$$

indeed by $y=\frac{\pi}2-x$

$$\tan x\cdot(\sin x-1)=\cot y\cdot (\cos y-1)=\frac{\cos y}{\sin y}\cdot y^2\cdot \frac{\cos y-1}{y^2}=$$

$$=\frac{y}{\sin y}\cdot y\cos y\cdot \frac{\cos y-1}{y^2}\to 1\cdot 0\cdot (-1/2)=0$$